# Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 webmin shows 196GB hard drive space but it's 1TB

Tags: server, partitioning, hard-drive, raid

I have loaded webmin on my Ubuntu Server 20.04.3. The dashboard of the webmin says 16.67 GB used of 196GB. But my disk size is not 196GB. I have a raid array of 1TB. If I click on hardware and look at the partition on local disks it shows two small partitions followed by a big partition of 952GB. So question is, why am I only being allowed to use 196GB from it?

```
NAME                        SIZE FSTYPE      LABEL MOUNTPOINT
sda                       931.5G
├─sda1                        1M
├─sda2                        1G ext4              /boot
└─sda3                    930.5G LVM2_member
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   200G ext4              /
sr0                        1024M
```

Comment: I guess that you have an LVM volume with 196GB in your array. Please help us by running the following command line, `lsblk -o name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint | grep -v 'snap'` and edit your original question to show the result. Please render the output as `code` in order to make it easy to read.

Comment: I've placed the result as code in my original question

Comment: You can do different things with the LVM system: Either use the yet not used space for backup or a snapshot or simply increase the size of the root partition. There are 'lv' tools for that purpose. You can find tutorials via the internet, for example, search for **ubuntu lvm guide**.

Comment: This is a good guide https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/